# Why reference of a view using a binding class is marked with @Nullable?

Tags: android, xml, android-viewbinding, kotlin-null-safety

I have a layout with some TextView and a CardView. Only the reference binding.mycardview returns an object `CardView?`, but according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding):

> Null safety: Since view binding creates direct references to views, there's no risk of a null pointer exception due to an invalid view ID. Additionally, when a view is only present in some configurations of a layout, the field containing its reference in the binding class is marked with @Nullable.

My layout row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cVComune"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/space"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvComune"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_label_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCap"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_label_medium"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivMail"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvComune" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPrefisso"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_label_medium"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPhone"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvComune" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAbitanti"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_label_medium"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivAbitanti"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvComune" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLink"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
                android:textColor="@color/hyperlink"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_label_medium"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCap" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvProvincia"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/space"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_label_medium"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRegione"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/space"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_label_medium"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvProvincia"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivMail"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/widthimg"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/space"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
                android:contentDescription="@string/codicepostale"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCap"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvComune"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/mail" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPhone"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/widthimg"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spaceimg"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
                android:contentDescription="@string/telefono"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCap"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivMail"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvComune"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/phone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivAbitanti"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/widthimg"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spaceimg"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
                android:contentDescription="@string/abitanti"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPrefisso"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPhone"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvComune"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/stick" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

So, why `RowBinding.tvLink` is an object `TextView` marked with `@NonNull` but `RowBinding.cVComune` is a `CardView?` marked `@Nullable`? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you have multiple versions of `row.xml`? For example, `res/layout/row.xml` and `res/layout-land/row.xml`? If the `CardView` isn't present in one of the two layout files, or if the `android:id` attribute isn't on the CardView, its type will be nullable.

You ought to be able to view the generated binding file in Android Studio by looking inside your module's `build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out` directory. That file should have a comment explaining why the view is nullable.

For example, here I deleted the `android:id` attribute from my `TextView` in the `layout-land` version of my layout file:

```
  /**
   * This binding is not available in all configurations.
   * <p>
   * Present:
   * <ul>
   *   <li>layout/</li>
   * </ul>
   *
   * Absent:
   * <ul>
   *   <li>layout-land/</li>
   * </ul>
   */
  @Nullable
  public final TextView text;
```